# Array don't store/displah whole string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, programming-languages

so I have this code :

```
char address[1000] ;

printf("Enter you address : ") ;
scanf("%s", &address) ;

printf(" Your address is : %s ", address) ;
```

When i type for example "New York City", only "New" will be displayed and I don't know why. Help please.
Thanks

Comment: drop the `&`. from `scanf("%s", &address) ;`

Comment: [man scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf): ***s** Matches a sequence of **non-white-space** characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.*

Comment: Of how many other questions is this a duplicate?  The answer isn't zero.  If you want the line to be read, use `fgets()` instead, being careful if you've previously read anything with `scanf()` because that usually leaves newlines in the input buffer and `fgets()` stops at the first newline.

Comment: Eugene Sh. Thanks, I tried it with "fgets". It"s now working. But I thought that "fgets" is only used with files ?

Comment: It is.  Stdin is a file.  Files aren't just for disks. Making the same I/O functions work for files-on-disks and files-on-terminals means that the average program can work with either, and need not know the difference.  (Files-on-terminals don't have names beyond the name of the terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use:

`scanf(" %999[^\n]", address )`

But probably will be better (maybe safer) to use `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char address[1000] ;

    printf("Enter you address : ") ;
    if ( fgets( address, sizeof(address), stdin) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Deal whith the Error\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("Your address is : %s ", address);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter you address : New York City
Your address is : New York City
```

@ Chris Dodd mentioned in its comment, about `fgets` and probably you should know (if you do not know already) that `fgets` add the `'\n'` too.

If you do not need it, you can remove it with the help of the `strcspn` function:

```
address[ strcspn( address, "\n" ) ] = 0;
```

You need to include `string.h`.

Comment: You missed a newline in your output -- this code will output a blank line at the end.

Comment: Thanks Michi, i tried both and they're working. But i want to know, what's the actual usage of "stdin" ?

Comment: Small suggestion: Use `sizeof(address)` instead of `1000` here. That way if someone shortens the buffer they can't forget to update the parameter.

Comment: @uliwitness Done. Thanks for observation.